# Python For i in range(len(str)): last iteration prints None

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
def fun(str):
    for i in range(len(str)):
        print(i)

string = 'abc'

print(fun(string))
```

print results are

```
0
1
2
None
```

if I change

```
for i in range(len(str)-1):
```

the last result is still None

Why is this?
And how do I stop it?

Answer (score 6):

When you call `print(fun('abc'))`, you first call `fun`, which indeed prints `1`, `2` and `3`, once `fun` completes, you print its return value. Since you didn't explicitly return anything, Python implicitly returns `None` for you.

To make a long story short - don't call `print` on `fun`, just call `fun`:

```
string = 'abc'

fun(string) # Here
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `0, 1, 2` from the print statement in `fun` function while `None` is getting printed by:

```
print(fun(string))
```

Since, by default a python function returns `None` that's why you are getting it here. You can directly call it without print statement.

```
fun(string)
```

Comment: ahh i see.  I was using print to debug doing an algorithm in ctci and it kept throwing me off lol.  thank you

Answer (score 2):

this is because you use print(fun(string)) and you have a print statement inside your function. So it executes the print inside your function and another print with no return value from the function so None.